Passing different environments as inputs to reusable workflow
I'm trying to set up a reusable workflow, calling it from a main workflow and passing as input just my different env names.
name: Call Reusable Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: ["feature/my_branch"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

jobs:
  ReuseableMatrixJobForDeployment:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        environment: [dev]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable_workflow.yml
    with:
      environment: ${{ matrix.environment }}

Inside reusable workflow, I want to set the env from input and use its secrets, how can I achieve that?
name: Reusable Workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  build-push-artifact:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: 'Echo inputs env'
        run: |
          echo ${{ inputs.environment }} -- This works
          echo ${{ secrets.VAR1 }} -- This just show blanks
          echo Prod id ${{ secrets.VAR2}} -- This just show blanks

I know that I won't be able to print the secret, but in this case shouldn't it echo like "****"? While trying to use it, it echoes just blank.
I tried to set up a multi context workflow, using a main workflow with matrix setup that will pass as parameters the env name.
That should be able to iterate the matrix env name list and run the reusable workflow for each env.

A reusable workflow doesn't work that way with secrets. You need to inherit them from the main workflow first (reference). To do so, you must set the secrets you need to use in the reusable workflow_call configuration. This will work if you use the reusable in the same repo than the main workflow (which seems to be the case as you're using environments). If you plan to share the reusable through an organization, you should use org secrets instead.

Thanks for clarification GuiFalourd.
So if I want to call the reusable job for more than an environment, e.g [dev, prod], there is still a way to combine a matrix strategic and call those jobs passing their env secrets?
Or do I need to create a separeted  workflow to call for which env?

Yes, this should be possible. You would need to add the secrets (secrets.VAR1 and secrets.VAR2) to the workflow_call setup in the reusable yaml. And when calling the reusable in the main workflow, add the secrets: inherit configuration field (as in the link I shared above)


Once written to GitHub, secrets have their value hidden in both web interface and the CLI. The only way to access the secret value is to use it in a GitHub Action. However, if you print the value in the job output, e.g. echo $MY_SECRET, GitHub might obfuscate that in the output to prevent secret values from inadvertently leaking.

https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/3397#discussioncomment-598311
